# How to populate custom fields in Shopware

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I was reading the documentation about custom fields in a Shopware 6 app: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/custom-data/custom-fields

While it is working (the custom fields are well created during the app setup) I would like to know what to do next.

How am I supposed to populate those fields or to allow a customer to fill them in the checkout for example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The custom fields show up in the administration on the detail pages of the `related entities` and the user can populate the fields there in the admin UI.

Another possibility is that you can populate the custom fields over the API by sending PATCH requests for the affected entities.

To add a custom field to the checkout you would have to change the template for the checkout page to add the form field there as well so that the field is sent to the server when the order is placed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually I have somes variables (UTM) that are present in the query string of the page. I would like to fill custom fields with these variables in the context of a Shopware 6 app (Cloud compatible). Do you think this is feasible? I've read that you can alter the templates but I still does not figure how to accomplish what I ask...